# What are the odds of rolling 100 6 sided die with a specific sequence of numbers.

Tags: statistics

I know how to calculate the odds of say rolling n number of dice and them being the same value (i.e. $1/6^{n}$) but is it the same if I want a specific set of values. For example, with a single roll of 100 dice (my hands are huge), if I wanted 15 ones, 30 fives, 10 twos, 5 threes, 20 sixes, and 20 fours. Is there a general expression for ANY single specific sequence? Or do I need to know the desired result first?

Comment: The probability depends on the pattern.  For example $50$ ones and $50$ twos is about $10^{29}$ times as likely as $100$ ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your example, the number of ways will be equal to the number of ways you can arrange a sequence of 15 ones, 30 fives, 10 twos, 5 threes, 20 sixes, and 20 fours. This is given by the following formula-
$$N=\frac {100!}{15!{\cdot}30!{\cdot}10!{\cdot}5!{\cdot}20!{\cdot}20!}$$
Where $100!$ represents the number of ways to arrange $100$ unique numbers while the denominators compensates for there being moe than one a particular number. This formula can easily be generalized for all cases.

Comment: You are going to want to divide that by $6^{100}$ to get the probability

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you're more likely to get all 100 dice of a single value than the specific mixed value? Is that correct?

Comment: Depends on the mixed value but either way you will have to divide by $6^{100}$ as that is the total number of cases.